# How I can return value from async block in swift

Tags: swift, multithreading

Please have a look into the code below:

```
backgroundthread.async {
    return self.mycallback() //return string, int etc
}
```

I want to return a value from an async block. I don't want any completion handler or any other workaround.

```
func getAppConfigFromDB(_ key: String) -> String 
{
   let value = String()
   backgroundthread.async {
      let inst = AppConfigDB.init(_APP_CONFIG_DB_PATH)
      value = inst.getConfigurationInfo(key) // I want to return from here.
   }
   return value
}


getAppConfigFromDB("path")
```

Comment: You have no choice but to use a completion handler. You can't return a value from an async call.

Comment: ok, is there any work around or custom template, we can use.

Comment: I agree with @rmaddy, completion handler is the only way to handling the results when the async task completes. They named it well!

Comment: Why do you wish to avoid a completion handler? What problem are you trying to solve where the simplest and proper solution is to be avoided for some reason?

Comment: Could you provide me completion handler, I want to see.

Comment: The way to get a return value from your function is to change the async block to a synchronous block, or an inefficient workaround to do the same thing.

Comment: There are countless example here and in the Swift APIs.

Comment: @hotpaw2, yes, I can try with sync block. Its long way to change my code but thats fine. Thanks. !!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like @rmaddy said, you have no other way than to use completion handlers.

```
func getAppConfigFromDB(_ key: String, completion: @escaping ((String) -> Void)) {
    let value = String()
    backgroundthread.async {
        let inst = AppConfigDB.init(_APP_CONFIG_DB_PATH)
        value = inst.getConfigurationInfo(key) // I want to return from here.
        completion(value)
    }
}
```

You call the method like this.

```
getAppConfigFromDB("") { (value) in
    // Use value to do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function would need a closure like so

```
func getAppConfigFromDB(_ key: String, completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
    backgroundthread.async {
        completion("string here")
    }    
}
```

When you call your function you would do

```
getAppConfigFromDB("key") { (returnedString) in
    //returnedString is Optional("string here")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing with `return self.mycallback()` is something like in

TypeScript:

```
String text = await someTask();
```

or in C#:

```
String text = someTask().result;
```

and from an async function:

```
String text = await someTask();
```

However this concept does not exist in swift (and i think Java too).

The only other method I can think of other than using a completion handler, is passing the results to another function (NOTE: If you intend on working on the main thread/UI Thread you will get an exception - you will need to wrap your call in   `DispatchQueue.main.async {/*Do stuff...*/}`) like so

```
    func startAsync {
        let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            guard let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.setResults(text: jsonString);
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    func setResults(text: String?){
        textView.text = text;
    }
```

full project:
https://github.com/AppLogics/SwiftAsyncTaskWithoutCompletionHandler